# How do I inject actual html from the model to the template?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my admin, I have a text area where the user can input html:

```
<ul>
  <li>blah</li>
</ul>
<p>
  Stuffs
</p>
```

When I push the above to my template and I view the source of the page, I get:

```
&lt;ul&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;blah&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
  Stuffs
&lt;/p&gt;
```

What should I do with my output so that I see actual html in the page source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need the 'safe' filter. As it's autoescaped.

```
{{ my_html|safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the template tags documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/), check the `autoescape` tag description.

Answer (score 0):

By “text area”, do you mean a `<textarea>`?

Because if so, escaping `<` to `&lt;` (et al) is what you *must* do inside a textarea or any other HTML element: Django is doing the Right Thing. You see the correct, decoded version of the text on the page; who cares what the source looks like?

If you don't escape the contents of a textarea you are not only generating invalid HTML, you're also opening yourself to attacks where the user inputs:

```
</textarea>
<script>
    steal(document.cookie);
    location.href= 'russian malware site';
    // etc.
</script>
```